# R$layout is defined multiple times

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I'm working in Android Studio 4.0.1 (Gradle 6.1.1)

When I'm building a project it generates two files in app\build\intermadiates\project_dex_archive\debug\out .jar with same name, and Debbuger triggers them as similar to R$layout.dex

I would very much like to get any information

I've already tried to Clean and Rebuild Project, deleting .gradle , and downgrading Gradle to 3.5 it doesn't helped

when I'm trying to open gradlew.bat, it closes immediately sending: Starting a Gradle Daemon, 1 incompatible Daemon could not be reused, use --status for details

Comment: Hi Ivan. Could you please try to build your project via CLI: `./gradlew build`? And then could you please update your question with the whole error message?

Comment: Hi, Max. when I'm trying to open gradlew.bat, it closes immediately sending: Starting a Gradle Daemon, 1 incompatible Daemon could not be reused, use --status for details.